# What is a reasonable size for an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone

I'm wondering what's a reasonable size for iPhone Apps. Right now I'm working on an iPhone game, and of course it loads fast into my device since I'm connected directly to it through a USB cable, but I've no idea how long it would actually take to download from the App Store.

In my case it's about 2mb in size, which is reasonable for a desktop or even a flash game, but I've no idea if this is reasonable size for the iPhone.

My other concern is what's the non-wifi download limit of the App Store? Occasionally there are Apps that won't download unless you've got a wifi connection. And personally I've never downloaded such apps, since it gives me a bad impression. So I'd definitely want to stay below that limit.

Also since I'm already asking about app sizes, it would be probably be useful to collect good sizes for other types of apps as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking through some of the games i have on my phone they weigh in around 7 or 8 mb a pop.  I think your 2mb will be fine.

One thing i can tell you for sure is that if you want to be distributable over the cell network your application has to be under 50 mb.  If you exceed this it will have to be downloaded using wifi or itunes on a computer.

Comment: Thanks for the numbers, they'll be useful for my next projects

Comment: Apple has changed this to 20mb.

Answer (score 4):

The 3g network is fast.  I wouldn't limit your development based on this - do exactly what you need to do to make your game as good as it can be, and people will download it even if it takes a tiny bit longer.  I've downloaded 10MB+ applications from the store over 3g and it might as well be a slow wi-fi connection, it's just that fast.

Also remember that many people purchase on their computers (hence a fast connection) and then just sync to the iPhone, especially those that are in areas with slower cellular networks.

Bottom line, size won't affect downloads, ratings will.

Comment: That is a good point of view. Size might not be that important. Within  reason of course ;)

Comment: Unless this is different for 3g vs edge, the app store limits you to 10 megabytes for distribution.

Comment: Just as a data point, Myst (the game) is 700MB; you probably wouldn't want to download it over 3g, but it's a valid app store app.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the resonable numbers being somewhat lower the limits:
Maximum app size ist 2GB
Application larger than 20MB won't be downloadable over a cellular connection

Answer (score 0):

I would try and keep it as small as possible. The app-store could probably support, say, a 100MB application, but it wont be nice to install for users.

The problem is installing via the phone - all you get is a simple progress bar, and most people have their phone auto-lock after 1 minute.. So, ideally the app would download in under a minute on an average connection..

Comment: I've a ~600 MB app on mine, app-store supports it quite well. :)

Comment: @Arafangion What app is that?  I would love to test downloading it

Comment: RIDBC Auslan Tutor. It's quite expensive, I fear. You must download it using a computer although the appstore allowed me to download it using the iPhone via wifi - but it took days! (Iphone's wifi is very slow compared to a computer).

Comment: iPhone's Wifi is the same as a computers wifi. There are several other circumstances that account for slowness.